# How the count the number of whitespaces between the first and second word in Java

Tags: java

I have a string that looks like the following:

```
Here    is a test
```

I want to return the number of whitespaces (4) between the first and second word **only** but I'm not quite sure how to do that. For my current attempt it counts the number of whitespaces of the entire string but I just need it between the first and second words and to then stop:

```
int spaceCount = 0;
for (char c : line.toCharArray()) {
    if (c == ' ') {
         spaceCount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: One basic solution could be to store the previous character into a variable and add it to your if : `if (previousChar == ' ' && currentChar != ' ') break;` else increment spaceCount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using regular expression

```
    String text = "Here    is a test";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\w)(\\s+)");

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("number of whitespaces = " + matcher.group().length());

    }
```

The regular expression searches for a word (an arbitrary, consecutive number non-whitespace characters) followed by whitespaces, so it doesn't matter if the text starts with whitespaces or not. The whitespaces are captured by a group and the length of the found group is returned. The regexp pattern can be precompiled and the code for matching a text can be put in a method:

```
private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\w)(\\s+)");

public static void main(String[] args) {

  String text = "Here    is a test";

  System.out.println("countWhitespaces(text) = " + countWhitespaces(text));
}

private static int countWhitespaces(String text) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        return matcher.group().length();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to start at the first whitespace and count until the last one.

```
int spaceCount = 0;
int i = line.indexOf(" "); // (You can replace this with a while loop to consider other whitespace characters)
while (line[i].equals(" ") && i < line.length) { // (Change criteria here if you want to consider other whitespace)
    i++;
    spaceCount++;
}
```

If whitespace includes more characters than just a space, replace the indexOf line with a while loop that iterates to the first whitespace, and change the other while loop's criteria to go while `" \n\t".contains(line[i])` (you can include whatever characters you consider whitespace in that string).

Answer (score 1):

```
int spaceCount = 0;
for (char c : line.toCharArray()) {
    if (c == ' ') {
         spaceCount++;
    } else if ( spaceCount > 0 ) {
          break;
    }
}
```

This assumes that there are no spaces before the first worid.

Answer (score 0):

I take your code, just edit a bit:

```
public int countSpace(String line) {
    int spaceCount = 0;
    int word = 0;
    boolean isSpace = false;
    for (char c : line.toCharArray()) {
        if (c == ' ') {
            ++spaceCount;
            isSpace = true;
            continue;
        }

        if (isSpace) {
            ++word;
            isSpace = false;
        }

        if (1 == word) {
            break;
        }
    }

    return spaceCount;
}
```

It's not the simplest solution and you should trim whitespace before use it.